# Issue with replacing apostrophe in URL string

Tags: javascript, replace

I've tried escape, replace, split and join and I can't seem to get rid of the ' in the category title:

`Over 60's`

```
var dropdown = document.getElementById("cat");
if ( dropdown.options[dropdown.selectedIndex].value > 0 ) {
        var currentText = this.options[this.selectedIndex].innerHTML;
        var currentSlug = currentText.replace(/ |'/g, function(match){ if (match === " " || match === "'" ){ return "-"; } return "";}).toLowerCase();
        location.href = "..url.. " + currentSlug;
} else {
        location.href = dropdown.baseURI;  
    }
}
dropdown.onchange = onCatChange;
```

Is there a different method required in this scenerio

Comment: you could just replace all non-alphanumeric characters, would that solve your problem?

Comment: I ended up using `currentText.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9 :]/g, "").replace(/\s/g, "-")`..etc to replace any non-alphanumeric characters and then anspaces left replace with -

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to replace a list of characters to a dash, you should put the characters inside the square brackets `[]`. For the apostrophe, escape it with a backslash.

```js
var s ="Text|Text'Text Text";
// replace all instances of space, pipe and apostrophe to dash
// and convert the string to lowercase
var t = s.replace(/[ |\']/g,'-').toLowerCase();
// use t here
alert(t);
```